# Why check if the request is POST in Django views.py?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm a beginner in Django so while learning I found something.

Some people are doing a request check for example:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        # Register user
        redirect()
    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/register.html')
```

So I found it unnecessary because the action and method are already specified it in my HTML form.

```
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
```

So for me, it makes no sense, as we only making a post a request to register.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Your html form could have implemented not just post method. So you need to check in view, whether it was exactly post or not - you never now.

Comment: You use POST to submit. But you *also* use that view to render the form in the first place.

Comment: @kosist absoultly if there is more than one form you need to chek, but if I have only one form and it was the only one to make the request in this case I'm right, right ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Woooooow I completely forgot that, thank you so much I understand why they are doing it now. I think it will be better to make a new view and passes form inputs rather than make register() handle two things

Comment: Well the reason this is done is that there is a third case, which is when there is an *invalid* submission. In that case we want to re-render the template with the invalid data and error messages. So it makes sense to keep the logic to render the template in the same place.

Comment: @DanielRoseman oh so making it like that to return the invalid data is easier than returning the data from another view with a redirect(), right ?

Answer (score 7):

Here you are using view for both [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) and [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) requests. More explanation is given in the code below:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':  # comes here when you are making a post request via submitting the form
        # Register user
        redirect()
    else:  # if you are making a get request, then code goes to this block
        return render(request,'accounts/register.html')  # this is for rendering the html page when you hit the url
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great

Answer (score 3):

Post requests are made to submit any user input to the server backend. To simply state your query, this is a basic flow of a web program:

1. Whenever a user visits a site by entering the url(https://example.com), then a `GET` request is submitted to the server as `GET / [status_code]`. So, even if the template in the requested url contains a 'POST' form, first a `GET` request is to be made.
2. Now if the user fills a form and submits the data using `POST` method, server gets a request as `POST / [status_code]`.

Hence, to handle both types of requests, you need to check the request method that is being made.
I think I have answered your query.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed workflow, it really helped me